# Why can't display google map V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Why can't display google map V2 ?
My code:
AnroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.daitran.mapversion2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.daitran.mapversion2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.daitran.mapversion2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.daitran.mapversion2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBTLEIcHn7wKQQC_q6y0YcJ7Ffw03PHfHs" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.daitran.mapversion2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

I run and get a error:

```
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daitran.mapversion2/com.daitran.mapversion2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1996)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1174)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:252)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at com.daitran.mapversion2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    ... 11 more
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4249)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
11-11 01:06:29.958: E/AndroidRuntime(27914):    ... 21 more
```

Can you help me?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MapFragment`

Change this

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Also check the docs

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Remove the below permissions. Check the link above for permissions under Specify app settings in the application manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="com.daitran.mapversion2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.daitran.mapversion2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: ok Thanks you. I change  SupportMapFragment to MapFragment. Map display on API > 12 ok. But I want display map with api 9

Comment: @user1497597 then edit your question no where you mentioned that. So how do you expect us to give a correct answer. Use `SupportMapFrament` Use support library. extend `FragmentActivity` Change min sdk to 9